# How can 'const' have an influence on the type of the variable?

Tags: javascript, boolean, constants

I've had this little problem where I wanted to check all checkboxes inside a specific area with the help of some javascript and a few jquery functions. I retrieved the value of the "select-all" checkbox and wanted to check/uncheck all other checkboxes under it.

Case 1: `status = (elt.checked == true);`
This gives me a string with the value `"true"` or `"false"` which, when put into a conditional statement, will always be seen as `true` since it's not an empty string.

Case 2: `const status = (elt.checked == true);`
This gives me a boolean with the value `true` or `false` which can actually be used in the conditional statement.

```
$(document).on('change', '.select-all input', function(e) {
    elt = e.target;
    status = (elt.checked == true);
    $(elt).closest('.files-list').find('input').each(function(i, e) {
        if (status)
            $(e).attr('checked', true);
        else
            $(e).removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

Why does this `const` modifier have any influence on the data type of the variable?

Comment: Because `window.status` already exists, and can only be a string. (using a different variable name would fix it)

Comment: Why are you using global variables in your function? Did you forget to declare `elt`  and `status`?

Comment: You should always use `const` or `let` to declare a variable (or, if you have a good reason, `var`.) In strict mode, your code would not be allowed so the problem wouldn't occur, so using strict mode is a good idea too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you a lot for the quick answer, I didn't know that window had this variable :).

Comment: I think your code boils down to this: `$(document).on('change', '.select-all input', function() { $(this).closest('.files-list').find('input').prop('checked', this.checked); });`